# Help Finding a Paper on Sunflower Free Systems

Tags: combinatorics

I am interested in one of the results from the following paper:

Abbott, H. L., and B. Gardner. "Remark on a combinatorial theorem of Erdos and Rado, Recent Progress in Combinatorics, WT Tutte, ed." (1969): 211-215.

However, I'm having a lot of difficulty finding it. Google Scholar has a result for it, but it's only the citation with no paper. One of the follow-up discussions from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163689/what-is-the-best-lower-bound-for-3-sunflowers indicates a link for the paper, but the link is broken. Using the notation from the linked question, I'm mainly just trying to find a proof that $f(3)=20$, so if there is some other proof of that out there, I'm content with not finding the paper. Thank you for your help!